# How can I get the search button textusing PlayWright end to end testing tool

Tags: javascript, playwright

How can I get the `search` button text in `PlayWright` end to end testing tool. I have tried below and getting `page.innerText(selector, options)` but getting undefined. Can someone please advise why the innerText method is not working here.

//homePage.js

```
const { expect } = require('@playwright/test');

exports.HomePage = class HomePage {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.getSearchButton = page.innerText(.RoundButton__root .RoundButton__root--blue');
      }

      async goto() {
        await this.page.goto('https://www.localsearch.com.au/');
      }
      
      async getSearchButtonText() {
        await this.getSearchButton ;
      }
      
}
```

//home.js

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { HomePage } = require('../pom/homePage');

    test('Verify Search button text', async ({ page }) => {
      const homePage = new HomePage(page);
      await homePage.goto();
      const text = await homePage.getSearchButtonText();
      console.log("Search text::"+text);
     
    });
```

Comment: The selector doesn't resolve to anything on the page I get, try `const text = await page.innerText('text=Discover thousands of local businessesSearch >> button');`, you can use `npx playwright codegen https://www.localsearch.com.au/` to have playwright pick selectors for you.

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky  Sorry this is not working `const text = await page.innerText('text=Discover thousands of local businessesSearch >> button');`